# JNDI LOOKUP Error Tomee OpenEJB NameNotFoundException

Tags: java, ejb, apache-tomee, openejb

Hi i am Working with openEJB in Tomee jaxrs(1.7.4) server, i have a Web project and a EJB project running on the same TomEE sever.

I have deployed the EJB project in the webapps folder of the TomEE server and can see the EJB's are starting when the server starts.

```
 INFO: Enterprise application "C:\Apache_Software\OPEN_EJB\Server\webapps\OpenEjbServer" loaded.
Sep 08, 2016 10:08:39 AM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createApplication
INFO: Assembling app: C:\Apache_Software\OPEN_EJB\Server\webapps\OpenEjbServer
Sep 08, 2016 10:08:39 AM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder bind
INFO: Jndi(name=calcRemote) --> Ejb(deployment-id=calc)
Sep 08, 2016 10:08:39 AM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder bind
INFO: Jndi(name=global/OpenEjbServer/calc!org.superbiz.stateless.basic.CalculatorBeanRemote) --> Ejb(deployment-id=calc)
Sep 08, 2016 10:08:39 AM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder bind
INFO: Jndi(name=global/OpenEjbServer/calc) --> Ejb(deployment-id=calc)
Sep 08, 2016 10:08:39 AM org.apache.openejb.cdi.CdiBuilder initSingleton
```

Below is one of the @Stateless beans in the EJB project

```
 @Remote
 public interface CalculatorBeanRemote {
   public int add(int a, int b);
 }

 @Stateless
 public class CalculatorBean implements CalculatorBeanRemote {
  @Override
   public int add(int a, int b) {
      return a + b;
   }
 }
```

from EJB project using servlet I can do the JNDI Lookup using the following code.

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.put("java.naming.factory.initial","org.apache.openejb.client.LocalInitialContextFactory");
p.put("java.naming.provider.url", "ejbd://localhost:4201");
Context remoteContext = new InitialContext(p);
    try {
        Object ojb = remoteContext.lookup("calcRemote");
    }catch(Exception e){}
```

When trying to do the same call when the EJB is deploy separately I get

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name "calcRemote" not found.
at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.naming.IvmContext.federate(IvmContext.java:197)
at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.naming.IvmContext.lookup(IvmContext.java:151)
at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.naming.ContextWrapper.lookup(ContextWrapper.java:115)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
```

How can I do a local or remote JNDI Lookup from Web project to the EJB when it is deployed on the same TomEE server or different TomEE Server?

What could be cause of this error? 
Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

you use a *Local* for a *remote* bean so it doesnt work, instead of LocalInitialContextFactory switch to remote one, check http://tomee.apache.org/clients.html for the detail

Comment: i tried with RemoteInitialContextFactory also in that case i am getting different error. ** WARNING: RequestFailed{server=http://localhost:8080} JNDI_LOOKUP:/calc {error=Cannot open input stream to server: }
org.apache.openejb.client.ClientRuntimeException: Invalid response from server: -1**

Comment: why one? side note: you can also use the name global/OpenEjbServer/calc!org.superbiz.stateless.basic.CalculatorBeanRemote (from EE 6)

Comment: as you suggested i tried still getting same error:  WARNING: RequestFailed{server=http://localhost:8080} JNDI_LOOKUP:global/OpenEjbServer/calc!org.superbiz.stateless.basic.CalculatorBeanRemote {error=Cannot open input stream to server: }
org.apache.openejb.client.ClientRuntimeException: Invalid response from server: -1

Comment: maybe you miss some configuration, check blacklist config (client AND server) on http://tomee.apache.org/ejbd-transport.html and ensure tomee webapp is deployed (see tomee.remote.support on http://tomee.apache.org/properties-listing.html )

Comment: Already i have enable the check for blacklist and whitelist and remote support for ejb Here are my settings:  'tomee.remote.support = true
tomee.serialization.class.blacklist = -
tomee.serialization.class.whitelist = * '

Comment: My scenario : i have 2 Tomee server running in 2 different machine lets say machine-A and machine-B in Machine-A i have deployed EJB project From machine-B i want to Access those bean how can i do that. please give some code snippets.  Appreciate any help

Comment: the previous tip works: set remote support on the one you target (server), set blacklist in conf/system.properties on *both* instances (client and server) and use remote initial context lookup.